# Can someone point me to a good migration guide from C# to Java?

Tags: c#, java, migration

I am a seasoned .Net developer and have a good grasp of OOP concepts. I will be working on a Java  project in the near future and was interested in knowing if someone could point me to a good migration guide for moving from C# 4.0 to Java.

Java equivalent for :

1. LINQ to Objects (I understand Java does not support anonymous types like C# does, but a good collections library would be helful)
2. ASP.Net MVC 3 (what are the cool kids using for building Java web applications these days)
3. Castle Windsor (something which supports a fluent registration api)
4. WCF 4.0, SOAP for the most part, REST some scenarios
5. Build - nant (something no xml?)
6. A language nuances guide (no lambdas, anonymous methods, etc.)

Thanks

Comment: the bit about nant sort of made me chuckle, take the n off and you will have the java build tool that started the whole dumb move to xml for build scripts in the first place.

Comment: @Matt Briggs: what, you miss *make* 's CR/LF issues between Un*ces and Windows?  And makefiles encoding issues? (when stupid developers used non-ASCII in files/directories names needed to be referenced from *make*)  Common... At least XML solved the nasty CR/LF and character encoding issues ;)  Agreed it's verbose, but I don't ever want to hear about CR/LF nor about character encoding issue again ;)

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r: Granted, but stuff that has come out of the ruby, javascript, python, and clojure communities (and probably more, I just have experience with those tools) are all vastly superior to the xml thing. holding make up as the only alternative is a bit of a straw man argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the following articles:

- ["A Comparison of Microsoft’s C# Programming Lanauge to Sun Microsystems’ Java Programming Langauge"](http://www.25hoursaday.com/CsharpVsJava.html)
- ["Java vs. C#: Code for Code Comparison"](http://www.javacamp.org/javavscsharp/) (a language nuances guide)
- ["C# vs Java Part 3: The Frameworks (Network, Reflection, Security, Text)"](http://simpleprogrammer.com/2010/02/12/c-vs-java-part-3-the-frameworks-network-reflection-security-text/)
- ["C# vs Java Part 3: The Frameworks (IO, DB, Concurrency, Collections)"](http://simpleprogrammer.com/2010/02/09/c-vs-java-part-3-the-frameworks-io-db-concurrency-collections/)

See also:

- ["Comparing C# and Java"](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2001/06/07/csharp_java.html)
- ["Comparing Java and C# Generics"](http://www.jprl.com/Blog/archive/development/2007/Aug-31.html)
- ["Learning Java from a .NET Developer’s Perspective"](http://www.chinhdo.com/20090206/learning-java-from-csharp/)
- ["The C# Programming Language for Java Developers"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms228602.aspx)

Related SO questions:

- ["Migrating a project from C# to Java"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740625/migrating-a-project-from-c-to-java)
- ["is there an effective tool to convert c# to java?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78811/is-there-an-effective-tool-to-convert-c-to-java)

Answer (score 2):

I havent been a java dev for *many* years, but IMO this is the coolest web framework for any static language that I have ever seen. And not by a little bit.

http://www.playframework.org/